# Filemask excluding subdirectories not honored

Tags: c#, winscp

I'm using WinSCP in combination with C# code.

What I want to do is to include a filemask:  `options.FileMask = "[a]*.*|*/";`.
Idea is to exclude all subdirectories for being synchronised.

However, the result is that nothing is synchronised!
Should I use a different mask?

Code for getting the files with the mask:

```
var result = session.GetFiles(_FTPRemoteDir, _FTPLocalDir, false, GetTransferOptions());
```

Xml log:

[image: xml log WinSCP]

```
  <group name="pwd" start="2020-06-25T11:33:22.957Z">
    <cwd>
      <cwd value="/" />
      <result success="true" />
    </cwd>
  </group>
  <group name="get  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer=&quot;binary&quot; -filemask=&quot;[a]*.*|*/&quot;  -- &quot;\SyncSetup&quot; &quot;D:\FTP\SyncFolder&quot;" start="2020-06-25T11:33:29.664Z">
  </group>
```

Session log:

```
< 2020-06-25 13:33:22.957 Script: /
> 2020-06-25 13:33:29.664 Script: get  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -filemask="[a]*.*|*/"  -- "\SyncSetup" "D:\FTP\SyncFolder"
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.666 Listing file "\SyncSetup".
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.666 Retrieving file information...
> 2020-06-25 13:33:29.666 PWD
< 2020-06-25 13:33:29.667 257 "/" is current directory.
> 2020-06-25 13:33:29.667 CWD /\SyncSetup
< 2020-06-25 13:33:29.669 250 CWD command successful.
> 2020-06-25 13:33:29.669 CWD /
< 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 250 CWD command successful.
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 Retrieving file information successful
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 \SyncSetup;D;0;1899-12-30T01:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "D:\FTP\" - total size: 0
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: SyncFolder
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: [a]*.*|*/; ResumeL: 0
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 File "/\SyncSetup" excluded from transfer
* 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 (ESkipFile) 
. 2020-06-25 13:33:29.671 Copying finished: Transferred: 0, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 0/s
```

As can be seen in the log: my _FTPRemoteDir (\SyncSetup) is being excluded by itself.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
I was missing the '*' in the remote dir.
So I should have `_FTPRemoteDir = "\SyncSetup\*"`.

Comment: It's primarily not the `*`, it's the backslash. More straightforward is to use [`Session.GetFilesToDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfilestodirectory) – With it, these details do not matter.

Comment: Guess the GetFilesToDirectory will not work with parallel download, is that correct?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The only limitation of `Session.GetFilesToDirectory` comparing to `Session.GetFiles` is that you cannot "rename" the files while downloading.

Comment: `Session.GetFilesToDirectory`and `Session.GetFiles` do not have the option to sync files in parallel, right?

Comment: OK, so it was an unrelated question. – This is Q&A site, not a chat, if you have a new question, please [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).